# Comparing the efficiecy of 2 run times

Tags: algorithms, efficiency

I have a heap with $n$ elements. 
$k$ represent a number that is the height of one of the elements in the tree.

I need to compare two run times and prove what i claim.

The 2 run times are: 
$$
(1)O(\lg n \cdot (\lg n - k))
$$

And: 
$$
(2)O(2^k \cdot \lg n)
$$

Where: 
$$
\lg n - k
$$
Is a constant value.

---

For the first run time formula, its seems that we get: $O(\lg n)$

But how do i find the run time (and prove) for the second run time?

Thanks.

Comment: Parts of this question could use interpretation guidance. a) in asymptotic resource requirement analysis, $n$ commonly is used to characterise problem size: How shall *$\lg n - k$ Is a constant value* be interpreted? b) `run time [for a] second run time` c) Comparing the efficiency of 2 run times

Answer (score 1):

$\log(n)-k$ is const $\implies$ $2^{\log(n)-k}$ is const $\implies O(2^{k} \cdot \log(n)) = O(2^{\log(n)-k} \cdot 2^{k} \cdot \log(n)) = O(2^{\log(n)} \cdot \log(n)) = O(n \cdot \log(n))$

Answer (score 0):

In case of heap the worst case height could be $O(\log n)$.

$O(2^k\cdot\log n) = O(2^{\log n} \cdot \log n) = O(n\log n)$

Answer (score 0):

Let $k=\lg(n)+c$.

$(1) = O(\lg(n)),$

$(2) = O(2^{\lg(n)+c}\lg(n))=O(n\log(n)).$